kafka connect in distributed mode can't create connector
I'm creating S3SourceConnector, using the jars from confluent,
I have kept my jars in  /usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect location and set  plugin.path to this in  connect-distributed.properties and connect-standalone.properties
when I start my worker pod in Standalone mode or Distributed mode, S3SourceConnector class plugin is loaded - no problem,
curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins | jq -- shows
"class": "io.confluent.conenct.s3.source.S3SourceConnector",
"type": "source",
"version": "2.6.0"

But in distributed mode  - when I try to create S3Source connector with curl command, I get following error
ERROR forwarding rest request
Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches "io.confluent.connect.s3.source.S3SourceConnector"
available connectors are ........

can't understand why this can't find the class, same works fine in standalone mode.
Can someone help me please.

Did you copy this correctly or is a typo? io.confluent.conenct?

Above results manually typed, as I can't copy paste from AWS workspace. it's typo
